# Java Converting String to Integer

Tags: java

I have the following codes below:

```
    private Integer mTarifId;

    public Integer getTarifId() {
        return mTarifId;
    }

    public void setTarifId(Integer tarifId) {
        this.mTarifId = tarifId;
    }
```

I have initialized a variable named 'mTarifId'. And i need to use it in the code below.

```
if (!Objects.equals(mTarifId, null)) {
            query = mEntityManager.createQuery("FROM TarifListeCalendrierEntity WHERE tarifListeId=:pId")
                    .setParameter("pId", mTarifId);
            List<TarifListeCalendrierEntity> tarifListCalendrierList = query.getResultList();
            if (!tarifListCalendrierList.isEmpty()) {
                TarifListeCalendrierEntity tarifListCalendrier = tarifListCalendrierList.get(0);
                request.setAttribute("tarif_list_calendrier", tarifListCalendrier);
            }
        }
```

But in order to do so i need to convert it to an integer in the 'doGet'

```
        String tarifId = request.getParameter("tarifid");

        if (!Objects.equals(tarifId, null)) {
            setTarifId(Integer.valueOf(tarifId));
        }else {
            setTarifId(null);
        }
```

Please help identify what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please describe error you are getting from the code sample.

Comment: When debugging this line of code is skipped 'if (!Objects.equals(mTarifId, null)) {' meaning the value of mTarifId is still null.

Comment: a friend told me to use something like this to get the value in mTarifId

mTarifId = request.getParameter("tarifid")

But when doing so i'm getting the error incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer

Comment: please focus on the main issue you are facing, is it getting null request parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Every time else condition is executed that why it's null.

```
String tarifId = request.getParameter("tarifid");

        if (tarifId!=null)
```

For Typecasting String to Integer.

```
Integer.parseInt(String);
```

Comment: I'm confused, please be more specific

Comment: Change your if condition as i mentioned  and let me know.

Comment: I modified it as suggested String tarifId = request.getParameter("tarifid");

        if (tarifId!=null) {
            setTarifId(Integer.valueOf(tarifId));
        }
        else {
            setTarifId(null);
        }

codes still skipped while debugging

Comment: Print your tarifId, may be it came null

Comment: i made a System.out.print(tarifId); but im not able to see the output in my wildfly console. can you help please..

Comment: It may be blank string. Please make sure if its not blank.

Answer (score 0):

can you maybe use try catch if there is any NumberFormatException.

Try this:

```
String tarifId = request.getParameter("tarifid");
Integer number;
try{
    number = Integer.valueOf(tarifId);
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    number = 0;
}
setTarifId(number)
```

Also, do you need your setTarifId() expecting an Integer, or int could be fine?

Answer (score 0):

Your actual issue is your request parameter.  It may happen that your mTarifId is not even set in request parameter named **tarifid**.

You have not mentioned how do you set it. So check that code if this parameter is actually set or not.

Comment: you are right...this is how it should be set i think 

mTarifId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("tarifid"));

Comment: It would throw **NUMBER FORMAT EXCEPTION** in case request,getParameter("tarifId") returns null or blank.

Answer (score 0):

This was what i needed:

```
mTarifId = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("tarifid"));
```

Comment: Instead of reposting another user's answer, you should simply upvote and/or accept their answer.